# How to test the following code using junit? Any solution would be appreciated

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit

How to write JUnit test case for the following code?

```
public static boolean validEmail(String emailAddress) {
    String EMAIL = "^[_A-Za-z0-9-]+(\\.[_A-Za-z0-9-]+)*@[A-Za-z0-9-]+(\\.[A-Za-z0-9-]+)*(\\.[A-Za-z]{2,})$";
    if (emailAddress.trim().matches(EMAIL)) {
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you tried something? Any doubt about something?

Comment: I would try it [this](https://github.com/junit-team/junit4/wiki/parameterized-tests) way.

Comment: Also: `return emailAddress.trim().matches(EMAIL);`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using JUnit 5, I would recommend this:

```
  @ParameterizedTest
  @CsvSource({"true, tester@mail.test", "false, unknown", "false, A@A"})
  void testIsValidEmail(boolean expected, String email) {
    assertEquals(expected, YourClass.validEmail(email));
  }
```

But you should put some effort in additional test parameters. You can read about Equivalence Partitioning and Boundary Value Analysis here https://www.istqb.org/downloads/send/51-ctfl2018/208-ctfl-2018-syllabus.html

Comment: Thank you Jens Dibbern. Appreciate your help.

Comment: You are welcome. Would you consider accepting the answer? That is the standard procedure in SO if the answer is working for you.